# Can Google see the screen when using Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: privacy, account-security, google, remote-desktop

I was wondering if Google can see my computer screen while I'm using Chrome Remote Desktop.

Let's assume there's my main PC named A and my other PC named B.
PC B will have the Chrome extension installed and is the PC that will be accessed remotely.

I use Chrome Remote Desktop to access PC B from PC A.

I log in to a VMware Windows guest on PC B that has a bridged network connection and launch Proton VPN and open a Firefox browser and search for the term password manager using duckduckgo.com search engine and go into some of the sites from the search results.

Then I use KeyPass password manager and create some password entries.

I don't think they can see the Internet network traffic from the VMware Windows guest as it's going straight out from the guest VM without relaying through Google remote desktop.

- But I was wondering if they can see the computer screen through Chrome Remote Desktop.
- Can Google see all this activity (the computer screen) and do we know if they are farming the data?

Answer (score 1):

Technically (whether intentional, e.g., to improve their advertising / machine learning models or unintentional e.g., bug) there's nothing stopping Google from seeing the computer screen.

However, Google like any other big tech companies take privacy breaches seriously as it will impact their public relations & ultimately stock price. By using Google remote desktop you agree to their terms/conditions. Here is an excerpt from their privacy policy: https://policies.google.com/privacy

"We also collect the content you create, upload, or receive from others when using our services. This includes things like email you write and receive, photos and videos you save, docs and spreadsheets you create, and comments you make on YouTube videos."

Chromium source code is supposedly open so you can check what is actually implemented https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/remoting/ but I don't know any guarantees this is what's deployed to your version of Chrome.

tldr: if you're sending Google (or any Cloud provider) data, you must trust them.